# Passing context between templatetags, django

Tags: django, model-view-controller, templatetags, django-context

I am using django to create a web-application.

I have created a template in where I load a `templatetag`. In this `templatetag` I load another `templatetag`. From the template I pass context to the first `templatetag`, but the context is not available from the second `templatetag` (inside the first `templatetag`) - see below.

I hope this makes sense, and that one of you have the answer.

---

Template snippit:

```
{% load templatetags %}
{% some_tag argument %}
```

---

some_tag Templatetag:

```
{% load templatetags %}
{% some_other_tag another_argument %}
```

---

some_other_tag Templatetag:

In this `templatetag` I am trying to access context to get user info i.e. using

```
request = context['request']
request.user
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the context to the subtemplate - and hence to the second template tag - is whatever is *returned* from the first template tag function. So you'll need to ensure that the request object is included in the dictionary you return there.

Comment: That would work, but is there no other way, e.g. making the context accesible from global?